# Rails duplicate confirm dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got a Rails app, and unfortunately, my confirm dialogs aren't working as expected. Here's the template snippet:

```
<%= button_to user_path, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
    <%= fa_icon 'trash-o', text: 'Delete' %>
<% end %>
```

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/users/name">
 <div>
   <input type="hidden" value="delete" name="_method">
   <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" data-confirm="Are you sure?">
     <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
     Delete
   </button>
  <input type="hidden" value="LSb8IIBGyQ+mB080WDdpEb16RYFJ26DTYbfMs8gc/F8=" name="authenticity_token">
  </div>
</form>
```

Now, when I click the Delete button, a confirm dialog is created. When I click OK, this shows up in the log:

```
Started GET "/users/name" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-21 14:53:02 +0200
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
Parameters: {"id"=>"name"}
```

That request returns a HTTP 200, and then another dialog is spawned. After clicking OK on that dialog, nothing happens, the dialog is simply omitted, and no delete request is sent.

Since there are already several questions similar to this one, here's what I've tried:

1. Looking for multiple javascript_include_tags. This is not the case.
2. Looking for multiple inclusions of javascript code. This is not the case, only jquery and jquery_ujs are in my application.js.
3. Turning off turbolinks. This did not help.
4. Using another browser (tried Chrome 36.0.1985.143 and Firefox 31.0)

UsersController code here:
https://gist.github.com/sonOfRa/3f7638e321a22f243ce9

Comment: you 're right about answer - can you post your UsersController?

Comment: What does UsersController#name do?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, these are non-numeric IDs, LDAP common names. It shows the user named 'name'. Adding UsersController above to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had originally accepted an answer here, but its poster deleted it. So for the record:

In this case, `link_to` should be used, rather than `button_to`

```
<%= link_to user_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
  <%= fa_icon 'trash-o', text: 'Delete' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your generated html not include `data-method = delete`. Your html should be

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete">
 <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
 Delete
```

try using below in your code :

```
<%= button_to user_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, class: 'btn btn-danger' do %>
   <%= fa_icon 'trash-o', text: 'Delete' %>
<% end %>
```

Second argument should be method type here. Hope this will help.

Comment: It has "delete" in the hidden field.

Comment: You were almost correct. It should be data-method="delete", but that doesn't happen swapping the arguments. Using link_to rather than button_to yields the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

might be a problem of jquery-ujs... FYI

data-confirm handler being applied twice
https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/384